# Evaluation of TF-IDF effectiveness in Gensim. Why are the results lists incomplete?

Tags: python, keyword, gensim, tf-idf

I would like to investigate how the TF-IDF score of particular words in document depends on the number of documents on which IDF is based. Unfortunately, the list of results that I receive vary in length and yet the number of words in the document is fixed... How to get TF-IDF results for all words in a document, regardless of the number of modeling documents?

I use the Gensim library to calculate the TF-IDF ratio. Here is my approach:

```py
from gensim import corpora
from gensim import models
from gensim.models import TfidfModel

# Suppose I have a list of words with a random distribution:
docs = [
    ['dog', 'cat', 'panda', 'deer', 'dog', 'elephant', 'panda', 'mouse', 'dog', 'panda', 'dog', 'python', 'penguin', 'lion', 'mouse'],
    ['cat', 'panda', 'rhino', 'lynx', 'panda', 'panda', 'panda', 'koala', 'mammoth', 'hamster', 'cat', 'koala', 'bear', 'fright'],
    ['dog', 'cat', 'elephant', 'panda', 'deer', 'deer', 'baloonfish', 'pig', 'owl', 'dove', 'camel', 'camel', 'camel'],
    ['dog', 'panda', 'mammoth', 'snake', 'lizard', 'elephant', 'partridge', 'alpaca', 'dog', 'dog', 'lizard', 'dog'],
    ['dog', 'owl', 'ostrich', 'porcupine', 'mouse', 'baloonfish', 'croc', 'lion', 'chimp',  'camel', 'doe']
]

# Each document has a certain number of tokens and unique types:
print([len(doc) for doc in docs])  # [15, 14, 13, 12, 11]
print([len(set(doc)) for doc in docs])  # [9, 9, 10, 8, 11]

# I create a dictionary that has 30 unique tokens...
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(docs)  # ['cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'elephant', 'lion', ...]
# ...and corpus containing individual instances of 5 documents
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in docs]  # [[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 1), ...], ...]

# now I'm training tfidf model and applying this model to all corpus documents then I check their length:
model = TfidfModel(corpus)
vector = model[corpus]
print([len(v) for v in vector])  # [9, 9, 10, 8, 11]
```

So far so good, but now I would like to compare these results with the results obtained for a smaller number of documents based on which the model is built. In order to do this I do the following:

```py
# now I'm training my tfidf model based only on first four documents in corpus:
new_model = TfidfModel(corpus[:4])
new_vector = new_model[corpus]
print([len(v) for v in new_vector])  # [8, 8, 9, 7, 6]

# based on first three:
new_model = TfidfModel(corpus[:3])
new_vector = new_model[corpus]
print([len(v) for v in new_vector])  # [7, 7, 8, 3, 6]

# based on first two:
new_model = TfidfModel(corpus[:2])
new_vector = new_model[corpus]
print([len(v) for v in new_vector])  # [7, 7, 3, 3, 3]
```

Can somebody explain to me why the number of results is decreasing? For example, the number of unique tokens in the first document is 9; but when the model is trained on fewer documents, the number of tokens suddenly drops to 8, 7, etc... And yet this document contains a fixed number of tokens. Why not all of them are included in the results? How to include them? Maybe I'm doing something wrong ... I'll be grateful for your help.